# Scala Slick implicit conversion of multiple types in raw SQL query

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick

I'm working on a Scala Play Framework 2.2 project, and I'm using play-slick 0.5.0.8 as my DB access layer.

I have the following code in one of my DAO objects:

```
def randomByBlahAndDate(blah: Blah, newerThan: LocalDate)(implicit s: Session): Option[Photo] = {
  sql"select * from photos where blah = $blah and imgDate > $newerThan order by rand()".as[Photo].headOption
}
```

As you can see, it does some tricky stuff like ordering by rand(), which is why I decided to go the raw SQL route. In any case, I get the following error on compilation:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter pconv: scala.slick.jdbc.SetParameter[(models.Blah.Blah, org.joda.time.LocalDate)]
```

It appears as though slick is trying to convert both of my types together, as a set... strange. I have an implicit type converter on my `Blah` enumeration, which works properly when inserting and fetching `Photo` objects:

```
def enumToStringMapper(enum: Enumeration) = MappedTypeMapper.base[enum.Value, String](
enum   => enum.toString,
string => enum.withName(string))

implicit val FormatMapper = enumToStringMapper(Blah)
```

I also `import com.github.tototoshi.slick.JodaSupport._` to support the `LocalDate` conversion. That also works just fine when inserting and fetching `Photo` objects.

Any ideas? Perhaps some sort of better query mechanism to support what I need (enum equality, date comparison, and rand() ordering)? Thanks.

**UPDATE: 2013-10-27**

I am now trying to do the following, with no luck:

```
def recordGuess(date: LocalDate, correctBlah: Blah, incorrectBlah: Blah, isCorrect: Boolean)(implicit s: Session) {
  val correctIncrement = if(isCorrect) 1L else 0L
  sqlu"insert into stats (date, correctBlah, incorrectBlah, impressions, guesses, correct) values ($date, $correctBlah, $incorrectBlah, 1, 1, $correctIncrement) on duplicate key update guesses = guesses + 1, correct = correct + $correctIncrement".first
}
```

Which again, doesn't work:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter pconv: scala.slick.jdbc.SetParameter[(org.joda.time.LocalDate, models.Blah.Blah, models.Blah.Blah)]
```

However, this time I see no good, easy way around it. Seems like Typesafe's `sql` and `sqlu` in slick don't support implicit conversions.

Comment: how do you know that sql and sqlu do not support implicit conversions?

Comment: Because of the error above, where it's not using existing implicit conversions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to find a solution to the implicit conversion problem, but I've found a workaround using more traditional slick syntax, with `scala.util.Random.shuffle`:

```
def randomByBlahAndDate(blah: Blah, newerThan: LocalDate)(implicit s: Session): Option[Photo] = {
  val photos = Query(Photos).where(_.imgDate > newerThan).where(_.blah === blah).run
  val r = new scala.util.Random(scala.compat.Platform.currentTime)
  r.shuffle(photos).headOption
}
```

I'm uncertain about the efficiency compared to using MySQL's `rand()`, but this will work for the time being.