# How to increment multiple fields on duplicate key with Scala Slick?

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick

I'm trying to do a MySQL `insert into ... on duplicate key update` statement using `play-slick`. You can see the SQL I'm using in the code below:

```
def recordGuess(date: LocalDate, correctBlah: Blah, incorrectBlah: Blah, isCorrect: Boolean)(implicit s: Session) {
  val correctIncrement = if(isCorrect) 1L else 0L
  sqlu"insert into stats (date, correctBlah, incorrectBlah, impressions, guesses, correct) values ($date, $correctBlah, $incorrectBlah, 1, 1, $correctIncrement) on duplicate key update guesses = guesses + 1, correct = correct + $correctIncrement".first
}
```

This single update statement does the work of two queries using just a single query and a unique index. The problem is that Slick doesn't seem to support implicit field conversion when using raw SQL (`sql` and `sqlu`). The error I get from the above is the following:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter pconv: scala.slick.jdbc.SetParameter[(org.joda.time.LocalDate, models.Blah.Blah, models.Blah.Blah)]
```

I get this despite using `com.github.tototoshi.slick.JodaSupport._` to support implicit conversion of `LocalDate`. I also have an implicit converter in `Blah` type which works using a normal select. Nobody was able to help me with that in this question: [Scala Slick implicit conversion of multiple types in raw SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535120/scala-slick-implicit-conversion-of-multiple-types-in-raw-sql-query)

In the [linked question above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535120/scala-slick-implicit-conversion-of-multiple-types-in-raw-sql-query), I was able to create a workaround, but I have no idea how to create a workaround for the `insert into ... on duplicate key update` problem. Any ideas? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

This seems to be the best that I can come up with, but it's pretty damn terrible, requiring multiple queries:

```
def findByDateAndBlahs(date: LocalDate, correctBlah: Blah, incorrectBlah: Blah)(implicit s: Session): Option[Stat] = {
  Query(Stats).where(_.date === date).where(_.correctBlah === correctBlah).where(_.incorrectBlah === incorrectBlah).run.headOption
}

def recordGuess(date: LocalDate, correctBlah: Blah, incorrectBlah: Blah, isCorrect: Boolean)(implicit s: Session) {
  val correctIncrement = if(isCorrect) 1L else 0L
  this.findByDateAndBlahs(date, correctBlah, incorrectBlah) match {
    case Some(stat) => {
      val updatedStat = new Stat(stat.id, stat.date, stat.correctBlah, stat.incorrectBlah, stat.impressions, stat.guesses + 1, stat.correct + correctIncrement)
      Stats.where(_.id === stat.id).update(updatedStat)
    }
    case None => this.insert(new Stat(None, date, correctBlah, incorrectBlah, 1L, 1L, correctIncrement))
}
```